# Map URL to empty route in ASP.NET MVC 2 from URL. URL displays blank page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, url-routing, maproute

If URL is 

http://localhost:54027/test1/test2/home

It shows home page

If URL is
 
http://localhost:54027/test1/test2/
It shows BLANK page

Following are the routes we have used

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "HomePage",
              "Test2",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", title = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
            routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductDetails", // Route name
            "Test2/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "Test2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "1" }
            );
```

If we try following URL it works fine

http://localhost:54027/test1/test2/**'**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductDetails", // Route name
            "Test2/{'}", // URL with *** ' *** parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created a dummy page as blank page and added Response.Redirect to home page
This is not the solution to the problem, but we worked around it.